# how to make node become selectable (add active class).?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

Can you please tell me how to make node become selectable (add active class) automatically? When user select any node it become selectable, in other word it become blue.
But now when I click by child button i got the child of "b", but it is not selectable. Can we make "b" selectable? When a user clicks on "child button", can we move this active class by using next and previous button? It goes to top and bottom when user click next and previous button.
http://jsfiddle.net/fuu94/44/

```
$('#child').click(function () {
for(i in $('#tree').jstree(true).get_node('b').children){    alert($('#tree').jstree(true).get_text($('#tree').jstree(true).get_node('b').children[i.toString()]));
}
});
```

Comment: please add complete code so i will check it at my end given you appropriate solution.

Comment: I already add all code in my fiddle.Please check my fiddle

Comment: @dheerendra do you get any idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set unset active on next and pre click:

```
  $('#next').click(function () {
    if($('.jstree-clicked').closest('li').next().length)
        $('.jstree-clicked').removeClass('jstree-clicked').closest('li').next().find('a:eq(0)').addClass('jstree-clicked')
  });
  $('#pre').click(function () {
     if($('.jstree-clicked').closest('li').prev().length)
        $('.jstree-clicked').removeClass('jstree-clicked').closest('li').prev().find('a:eq(0)').addClass('jstree-clicked')
  });
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fuu94/45/)**

Comment: i don't want to add active class on button .I want on element

Comment: @user944513: it is on elements.

Comment: no working on my side .when I click child it is not select b element

Comment: I need if user first click "child" button "b" become selectable

Comment: can we get information of child node as we get on "child button" of "b".can we get information of selectable child on pre and next button

Comment: yes I am getting But when I go to next example "c" i need it information

Answer (score 0):

You can make 'b' selectable by using select_node(node). http://jsfiddle.net/23NAG`$('#tree').jstree(true)
  .select_node('b');` from http://www.jstree.com/docs/interaction/

The next and previous can use the same select_node using the child ids.